# Animate a shrinking circle on an image

Tags: .net, wpf, image, animation

I have a WPF application with an image in the window.  When a certain event is triggered, I want to draw the user's attention to a point on the image by animating a circle that shrinks to nothing at the point of interest. Actually, I want this animation to repeat three times to ensure that the user sees the shrinking circle and his eyes are drawn to the point of interest.

How would you recommend that I do this in WPF?

Comment: With a DoubleAnimation that animates the RadiusX and RadiusY properties of an EllipseGeometry in Path.

Comment: You can also animate an opacity mask that 'lights up' the area of interest.

Comment: @Clemens: Thanks for the info.  It worked but I am not able to figure out how to keep the circle at the same relative position on the image when I resize the window (and the image, too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will get your animation working. You will need some work to find the position (point) where you want to place the circle.

```
  <Canvas Height="40" Width="40" >

                <Path Fill="Red" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <EllipseGeometry x:Name="circleGeometry" Center="100,100" RadiusX="40" RadiusY="40" />
                    </Path.Data>
                    <Path.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Path.Loaded">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>                                   
                                    <DoubleAnimation 
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="circleGeometry" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="RadiusX" AutoReverse="True"
                                            Duration="0:0:3" To="5" RepeatBehavior="0:0:18"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation 
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="circleGeometry" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="RadiusY" AutoReverse="True" 
                                            Duration="0:0:3" To="5" RepeatBehavior="0:0:18"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Path.Triggers>
                </Path>
            </Canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks.  That is essentially the code I wrote after @Clemens suggestion.  I bound the Center to a Point property on my view model but I have not yet discovered how to make the ellipse's center shift appropriately as the window and image are resized.

Comment: Two options (there could be more).
1. Host this ellipse inside a tooltip
2. Use adorner to get the position for this ellipse

Answer (score 0):

To animate the Center Property, use `PointAnimation` and not `DoubleAnimation`.
`DoubleAnimation` should still be used for the `RadiusX` and `RadiusY` however.